# Why do the probabilities not match?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I came up with this problem myself:

**There is a deck of 52 playing cards. A hand contains 5 of them.**

**You pull a hand from deck. What is the probability of no Queens in it?**

**You pull a hand from deck. What is the probability of at least 1 Queen in it?**

*The two pulls are independent: the 5 cards pulled the first time are returned to the deck and then the second hand is pulled.*

The way I understand it:

---

$P_{✘Q}=\frac{_{48}C_{5}}{_{52}C_{5}}$, where:

$_{48}C_{5}$ - the number of combinations of 48 cards (cards that aren't Queens) in one hand of 5 cards.

$_{52}C_{5}$ - the number of combinations of all 52 cards in one hand of 5 cards.

$P_{✘Q}=\frac{_{48}C_{5}}{_{52}C_{5}}=0.64884...$ = 64.9 %

---

$P_{✔Q}=\frac{_1C_1\times_{48}C_{4}}{_{52}C_{5}}+\frac{_2C_2\times_{48}C_{3}}{_{52}C_{5}}+\frac{_3C_3\times_{48}C_{2}}{_{52}C_{5}}+\frac{_4C_4\times_{48}C_{1}}{_{52}C_{5}}$, where:

$_1C_1$ - $_2C_2$ - $_3C_3$ - $_4C_4$ - the number of combinations of 1, 2, 3 and 4 Queens respectively.

$_{48}C_{4}$ - $_{48}C_{3}$ -$_{48}C_{2}$ -$_{48}C_{1}$ - the number of combinations of 48 cards in the deck that are not Queens.

$_{52}C_{5}$ - the total number of combinations of all 52 cards in one hand of 5 cards.

$_1C_1={_2}C_2={_3}C_3={_4}C_4=1$, therefore:

$P_{✔Q}=\frac{_{48}C_{4}}{_{52}C_{5}}+\frac{_{48}C_{3}}{_{52}C_{5}}+\frac{_{48}C_{2}}{_{52}C_{5}}+\frac{_{48}C_{1}}{_{52}C_{5}}=0.08197...$ = 8.2 %

---

How come the probability of getting no Queens is 65% while the probability of getting at least 1 is 8.2%? Shouldn't 100% - 65% = 35% be equal to the probability of getting at least 1 Queen?

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: The number of combinations of 1, 2, 3 queens among four cards is not 1, but rather 4, 6 and 4 respectively, as given by $_4C_1, {_4}C_2, {_4}C_3$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to check that... . Thank you, I get it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $i \choose i$ to represent the queens in the second instance where the hands include queens, it should be  $4 \choose i$.  So for example, there should be 4 ways to choose 1 queen, 6 ways to choose 2 queen, etc.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!